# How to get an index of a list element in elixir?

Tags: list, indexing, elixir, element

I have

```
>> list = ["a","b","c"]
```

and I need to get the index of the elements and create a new list that follows

```
>> list_2 = [[1,"a"], [2,"b"], [3,c]]
```

to create the new list I used

```
lista = Enum.flat_map(list, fn x -> [index,x] end)
```

but I can't find a function like to get the "index" value

Comment: `list_2 = Enum.with_index(list)` might be what you want but it gives tuples rather than internal lists: `[{"a", 0}, {"b", 1}, {"c", 2}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Enum.zip/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html?#zip/2) is your friend here.

```rb
list = ~w[a b c]
#⇒ ["a", "b", "c"]

list_2 = Enum.zip(1..3, list)
#⇒ [{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}]
```

or, if the size is unknown upfront, you might

```rb
Enum.zip(Stream.iterate(1, & &1 + 1), list)
#⇒ [{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}]
```

to get a lists, not tuples, simply map the result

```rb
1
|> Stream.iterate(& &1+1)
|> Enum.zip(list)
|> Enum.map(&Tuple.to_list/1)
#⇒ [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"]]
```

---

Another way would be to use [`Enum.with_index/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html?#with_index/1)

```rb
list
|> Enum.with_index(1)
|> Enum.map(fn {e, i} -> [i, e] end)
#⇒ [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"]]
```

Answer (score 13):

```
list = ["a","b","c"]
list_2 = Enum.with_index(list)
```

gives

```
[{"a", 0}, {"b", 1}, {"c", 2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the below answer is not related to asked question, but I'm sure it will help some in the feature.

In my case, I have to add an index to an array of lists/map.
So I did the below:

```
formatted_list = [%{"map 1": 1}, %{"map 2": 2}]
list_with_index = formatted_list
|> Enum.with_index(1)
|> Enum.map(fn {e, i} -> Map.put(e, :index, i) end)
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "index": 1,
        "map 1": 1
    },
    {
        "index": 2,
        "map 2": 2
    }
]
```